# Why does islower always return true even when there are digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This piece of code uses `isdigit()` and `islower()` which both check if a string includes only numbers (`isdigit`) or only lowercase letters (`islower`).

If the string given through password contains only numbers or lowercase letters the value should return true and print *only numbers* if the string only contains numbers or *only letters* if the string contains only letters, which it does.

However if the password contains numbers and letters for example `"12345qwerty"` it should return the value false, and go onto the `elif` statement to check if it has a number or letter included to say *add 5 points*, and if it still doesn't then it will say *try again* but it doesn't. It still returns the value as True and print the `if` statements argument which doesn't make sense, since the password `"12345qwerty"` contain both letters and numbers and should be returned as false.

```
import re
password = input("")
if password.isdigit():
    print("only numbers ")
elif re.search("[1-9]", password):
    print("thats 5 points")
else:
    print("try again")

if password.islower():
   print("only letters ")
elif re.search("[a-z]", password):
   print("thats 5 points")
else:
   print("try again")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.islower()` returns true *when there are no uppercase letters in the string and there is at least one lowercase letter*. That's not the same thing as *all* characters being letters.

A string with a mix of letters and numbers produces True as well, provided all letters are lowercase:

```
>>> 'a42b'.islower()
True
>>> 'a42B'.islower()
False
```

This is clearly [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower):

> Return true if all cased characters [4] in the string are lowercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.
>
> [4] Cased characters are those with general category property being one of “Lu” (Letter, uppercase), “Ll” (Letter, lowercase), or “Lt” (Letter, titlecase).

If you wanted to test if there were only letters, use [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> 'a42B'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'aB'.isalpha()
True
```

You can combine that with `str.islower()` to test if there are only lowercase letters:

```
if password.isalpha() and password.islower():
    # only lowercase letters, nothing else.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` to determine if the string has booth numbers and letters and build your cases around that function:

```
s = "12345qwerty"
def get_val(s):
  return not (any(i.isdigit() for i in s) and any(i.islower() for i in s))
print(get_val(s))
```

Comment: Is it not possible to keep it how it is or the reason why it doesn't work if not its fine, i'll happily try the code thank you